# Тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

(а если объект ассиметричен (-) нужно увеличить степень ассиметрии)

Ресурс такой резины на истирание в режиме сухого трения превышает основу в 6—10 раз, а в режиме работы в масляной среде (-) до 100 раз. Температурный режим по теплостойкости увеличивается на 30–500С, по хладостойкости (-) на 10–200С.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли здесь тире? Знаю, что путаюсь на ровном месте и все же...

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка тире возможна , если вам нужно логически подчеркнуть , выделить числительное. Однако при отсутствии паузы  тире не ставится. См. Русский язык. Справочник-практикум. Д.Э. Розенталь. Стр.131,133.
Что касается первого предложения,лучше поставить запятую.

Comment: Это вы имеете в виду это? 
"Примечание. В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится, например Температура плавления золота 1064,4; Грузоподъемность крана 2,5 т, вычет стрелы 5 м". 

Да, я вспоминаю, что это читала, но не могла вспомнить - где.

Comment: Да. Но см.также стр.133.